# How to unwrap a cube into a LINEAR Cubemap (all sides next to each other)?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, mesh, uv

Ok, I have a cube that I need to unwrap into a linear cube map like the one in bottom left:

[image]

All tutorials reference the T shape. I tried unwrap by cube projection, and then tried arranging the UVs by hand, by they're not perfectly placed. Pack islands just screws it up.

How can I unwrap in a straight line, or align them on a linear cube map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What problem do you encounter when you try to do it manually? You could do it this way: choose to unwrap with *Smart UV Project* option (and a marge of 0.03 for example), then in the *UV/Image Editor*, choose the Vertex snap mode, and rearrange your faces holding ctrl to make them snap. Does it answer?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1: Unwrap the cube using the **Reset** option. This will stack all the faces one on top of the other Each completely filling the UV space.
[image]

2: Edit each of the UV islands (faces) so that they are orientated correctly.
[image]

3: In the UV editor Properties side panel, enable the **Normalized** option. Doing this will mean if you select one of the islands and move it 1 unit in the X axis it will move exactly one UV space to the right. (Disabled it would move only 1 pixel).

4: Face +X is already correctly positioned (first in the line).

In the 3D editor select face -X.

5: In the UV editor move this -X face UV island 1 Unit to the right. **G X 1 Enter**
[image]

6: In the 3D editor select the next face in the line, +Y.

Back in the UV editor move this select island 2 units, **G X 2 Enter**.

Repeat for the remaining faces, **G X 3 Enter**.     **G X 4 Enter**.  **G X 5 Enter**.
[image]

7: UV Editor, **UV**'s menu check **Constrains to Image Bounds**

8: Set the Scaling pivot point to **2D Cursor**.

9: Using the UV Properties panel, **Display** menu, set the 2D cursor location to the 0.0  0.0 position in the UV space.

10: To get the line of UV islands exactly back into the UV space we need to scale them by 1/6. **S 0.16666666 Enter**.
[image]